# How to state action happening before another in the distant past

Tags: grammar

Suppose I wrote something 5 months ago. 3 months ago I forgot I wrote what I wrote. How do I state this?

- I'd forgotten I ever wrote that
- I'd forgotten I'd ever written that
- something else entirely?

---

EDIT:
Here's the complete sentence that got me thinking in the first place:

"Yeah, I found the answer some time ago, but by that point I'd forgotten I ever posted this question."

As you see, I forgot doesn't really work here (the act of forgetting occurs before the act of finding an answer, itself an action in the past).

Comment: I think you mean "I forgot I had ever written that".

Comment: There are many combinations that would work.  I don’t see a problem with either of the two you’ve got.